# Search for issues on GitHub that have a comment by someone else than the author

Tags: rest, github

As a way to keep track of issues and PRs on a GitHub repository that haven't been responded to yet, I'm looking for a way to do a search for all issues/prs that have:

- either no comments
- or comments only by the author of the issue/pr

Note that I'm doing this programmatically, using GitHub's REST API (in particular the [Issues request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#list-repository-issues)).

One idea is to search by number of comments as [indicated here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-number-of-comments) (`comments:>0`) but this won't work if the person who created the issue is also the one who posted the comments. I'm only interested in finding issues that have not had any other comments from other people.

I'd love to be able to do something like `comments:>0 -commenter:$AUTHOR` where `$AUTHOR` would be a way to dynamically refer to the author of the issue/pr.

I don't want to have to do this with several requests if possible. But I'm doubting that this is possible at all. Any ideas?